# How to make an average of a variable assigned to individuals within a category?

Tags: r, plot, average, categorical-data

I have a big data set which could be represented something like this:

```
plot 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 7
fate S M S S M S S S M S S M M
```

where plot is a location, and fate is either "survivorship" or "mortality" ( a plant lives or dies.) The plot number of a plant corresponds to the fate under it. Thus in plot 5 there are 4 plants. 3 of them survive, 1 dies.

I want to figure out a way to make R calculate the fraction of individuals that survive in each plot for all of these. It is proving very challenging.

Example: Plot 5 would return a survivorship value of 3/4 or 75%
                Plot 3 would return a survivorship value of 2/3 or 66%

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

#### Data

```
structure(list(plot = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7
), fate = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("M", "S"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("plot", 
"fate"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I've edited the question; Next time please `dput` a piece of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution with `dplyr`; I've created `valu` column with 1 if survived and 0 if not. After that it is only a matter of sum the 1's and divide them by the total number of elements of plot.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(plot) %>%
       mutate(valu = ifelse(fate == "S", 1, 0)) %>%
       mutate(perce = (sum(valu)/n() )*100 )

Source: local data frame [13 x 4]
Groups: plot

   plot fate valu     perce
1     1    S    1 100.00000
2     2    M    0   0.00000
3     3    S    1  66.66667
4     3    S    1  66.66667
5     3    M    0  66.66667
6     4    S    1 100.00000
7     4    S    1 100.00000
8     5    S    1  75.00000
9     5    M    0  75.00000
10    5    S    1  75.00000
11    5    S    1  75.00000
12    6    M    0   0.00000
13    7    M    0   0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. Here's one:

```
plot <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,7)
fate <- as.factor(c("S","M","S","S","M","S","S","S","M","S","S","M","M"))
sapply(lapply(split(fate, plot), function(x) round(prop.table(table(x))*100, 2 )), "[", "S")
#   1.S    2.S    3.S    4.S    5.S    6.S    7.S 
# 100.00   0.00  66.67 100.00  75.00   0.00   0.00
```