# R: calculate the quotient of 2 columns by ID

Tags: r, percentage

Here is my data:

```
ID      nb     ecart    
ID1     3       NA  
ID1     3       0    
ID1     3       1.5 
ID2     2       NA  
ID2     2       648 
ID3     4       NA 
ID3     4       0  
ID3     4       0 
ID3     4       7
```

I want to calculate the percentage of number of ecart which=="0" for each ID.

nb is the variable which shows the number of rows for each ID.

The exceped result:

```
ID      nb     ecart    percentage
ID1     3       NA        NA
ID1     3       0        1/3
ID1     3       1.5       NA
ID2     2       NA        NA
ID2     2       648       NA
ID3     4       NA        NA
ID3     4       0        2/4
ID3     4       0        2/4
ID3     4       7         NA
```

Hope to get your answer soon! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439306/how-to-make-an-average-of-a-variable-assigned-to-individuals-within-a-category/31439514#31439514); furthermore you output is note clear because `ecart == 0 ` is 2/4 for `ID3`

Comment: @SabDeM  I've updated. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: Do you really want `1/3` or do you want `.333`

Comment: 1/3 is better for me

Comment: Why `1/3` is better? It will be a character and you can't manipulate it? You should keep it numeric.

Comment: @DavidArenburg unless he's done manipulating and just wants it for pretty printing...

Comment: A base R option is `with(df1, ave(ecart==0, ID, FUN= function(x) NA^(!x)*sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)/length(x)))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick and efficient `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ecart == 0L, percentage := round(.N / nb, 2L), by = ID]
#     ID nb ecart percentage
# 1: ID1  3    NA         NA
# 2: ID1  3   0.0       0.33
# 3: ID1  3   1.5         NA
# 4: ID2  2    NA         NA
# 5: ID2  2 648.0         NA
# 6: ID3  4    NA         NA
# 7: ID3  4   0.0       0.50
# 8: ID3  4   0.0       0.50
# 9: ID3  4   7.0         NA
```

How this works: This will modify the values of `percentage` *by reference* only when `ecart == 0L` by calculating the size of the subgroup (using `.N`) divided by `nb`

---

Or (as commented by @CathG), if you want a pretty character print instead of a numerical value, you can do

```
setDT(df)[ecart == 0L, percentage := paste0(.N, "/", nb), by = ID]
```

---

Or if you prefer to use a binary join

```
setkey(setDT(df), ecart)[.(0L), percentage := paste0(.N, "/", nb), by = ID]
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico I didn't "assume" this is what the OP said himself. And I quote: "*nb is the variable which shows the number of rows for each ID*".

Comment: very true! i swear i'm part blind.

Comment: or `setDT(df)[ecart==0L, percentage:=paste0(.N, "/", nb), by=ID]` ;-)

Comment: @ MichaelChirico what's the meaning of  full .N?

Comment: @velvetrock exactly what you said yourself (sorry for not reading your question more carefully). I said "full" do indicate `df[,.N,by=ID]` as opposed to the "conditional" used in the answer: `df[ecart==0L,.N,by=ID]`

Comment: There is a problem. The first `ecart` of each ID is always equal to NA, so the percentage of the number of 0 will never be 100%. But with the funciton  `round(.N / nb, 2L)`, there are some 100% as the result.

Comment: And by using the function with `paste0(.N, "/", nb)` to ma data, the result is correct, but I will not be able to manipulate the data :(

Comment: Don't use `round` then. Or make it less sensitive and put 4 instead of 2, for example

Comment: It doesn't work by puting 4 or 8 instead of 2. So after using `paste0`, I can not transfer my data to numetic?

Comment: How many observations do you have in a group? You can remove `round` completely as in `setDT(df)[ecart == 0L, percentage := .N / nb, by = ID]`

Comment: I have about 30k observations. And it doesn't work neither:(

Comment: So did you try without `round` or not? It will equivalent to the `paste`. Again, just try `setDT(df)[ecart == 0L, percentage := .N / nb, by = ID]`

Comment: What does it mean "it's not working"? What do you get? it can't fail. it does the same thing as the `paste` option does, so if the `paste` works, this should work to.

Comment: There are also some `percentage=1`

Comment: Ah sorry for my mistake! `paste` is not work neither. I uesd `which(percentage==1)` and it gives me nothing so i thought it works. But actually, threr are some `percentage==2/2`...

Comment: Maybe you didn't calculate `nb` correctly? I can't tell what's happening if I don't have an example. Can you show a small subset of the data where you see `percentage==2/2`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83512/discussion-between-velvetrock-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `dplyr` answer.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(percentage =
         ifelse(is.na(ecart),
                NA,
                sum(ecart == 0, na.rm = TRUE)/n()))
```